# How to fix zramswap error?

Tags: ubuntu, dpkg, zram

I installed `zramswap-enabler` on Ubuntu 11.10 using the ppa but when installing programs or running system upgrades I get this error:

```
Setting up zramswap-enabler (0.2.1-0~12~oneiric1) ...
start: Job failed to start
invoke-rc.d: initscript zramswap, action "start" failed.
dpkg: error processing zramswap-enabler (--configure):
 subprocess installed post-installation script returned error exit status 1
No apport report written because MaxReports is reached already
                                                              Errors were encountered while processing:
 zramswap-enabler
E: Sub-process /usr/bin/dpkg returned an error code (1)
```

Please let me know how to fix it.

Comment: solved the problem by install the precise package and now all works fine again ...

Comment: how / where ? what repository ? I'm new to Linux. I am running Ubuntu 11.04

Answer (score 1):

Had the same problem. Just download/install `zramswap-enabler_0.2.1-0~13~precise1_all.deb` from launchpad, everything seems to be working correctly.